# Rich HTML - No Limitations

Tags: 2010, column, custom, html, rich-text

I have followed instructions (basically exactly the code in the link) on how to create a unrestricted HTML field:
http://blog.mastykarz.nl/publishing-rich-html-no-limitations-sharepoint-2010/

I am able to deploy the custom field and add it to a custom list, but when adding HTML to the custom column, it just shows the HTML code. Strange thing is in editing mode or when going to view the individual list items, the HTML code is displayed correctly.

Viewing a specific item displays correctly (notice on the page in the background, it just shows the HTML code):

[image]

I have done a bit of debugging and it seems like Sharepoint is adding some extra HTML encoding for some reason when displaying on the page, but not when viewing the item. <strike>Even adding plain text, some HTML code is added to the text.</strike> So, like when adding any HTML through *Markup->HTML->Edit HTML Source*, Sharepoint adds encoded HTML code on top of the HTML code I entered. For that yahoo List Item #2, I actually only entered:

```
Another Link:<a href="http://www.yahoo.com/" data-analytics="Tracked Link">Yahoo!</a>​​​​
```

In the debugger, it comes in like this:

```
Another Link:&lt;a href=&quot;<a href=\"http://www.yahoo.com/\">http://www.yahoo.com/</a>&quot; data-analytics=&quot;Tracked Link&quot;&gt;Yahoo!&lt;/a&gt;​​​&lt;span id=&quot;ms-rterangecursor-start&quot; style=&quot;display: none;&quot;&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span id=&quot;ms-rterangecursor-end&quot; style=&quot;display: none;&quot;&gt;&lt;/span&gt;
```

I don't understand what is going on between adding the HTML code (with Edit HTML Source) and it going through the custom Visual Studio field.

Am I missing something here? Thanks for any help.

Comment: what do you exactly want? to create html field like part of page or something else?

Comment: Pretty much a list where one column accepts HTML and displays it with links, formatting, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an explanation to achieve this:
http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/using-calculated-columns-to-write-html/
or here
http://www.balestra.be/2010/01/write-html-code-in-sharepoint-via-calculated-columns.html

idea is to create calculated column with multiple column of rich text.
Also you should add javascript into content web editor of page where you would put your list. Script is shown at the link I posted above.

Comment: That is all outdated methods unless you are on SharePoint 2007. If you want HTML & JavaScript in a Calculated Column read: http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How

Comment: Thanks for the responses thus far. I may look into the HTML/Javascript approach if I can't get this custom field working. I have figured out one thing though. Sharepoint automatically formats links (i.e. www.google.com, www.yahoo.com, etc.) and if I am able to disable this behavior, the custom field would work I believe. Decoding the text returned from the list displays everything correctly outside of all the links. Anyone know of any way of disabling of the autoformatting of links/hyperlinks? Or if this is even possible?